# Multi Threading with continious events from threads blocks UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have an application which creates **n** number of threads. Each thread is responsible for interacting with a system through TCP sockets and updates the status (Is Online , other Data from the system) to Data base as well as  back to UI which is populated / updated in the grid as per the data.

When the number of thread increases UI goes to non responsive mode. Requirement is all the threads should execute in parallel so that there is no delay in status updates.
If I use ThreadPool it may cause delay in status updation. Any help is appreciated

Comment: If the UI thread if constantly receiving update events then it will be very busy and unresponsive. You need to limit the events fired on the UI thread somehow. Consider only firing an event if something has changed, get the worker threads to determine this

Comment: I tried ignoring the events and still the problem persists. By any chance is it possible that the Threads created from UI will block the UI ? , since all my threads are created from UI Thread

Comment: @alban You would need to show us your code for us to help you with anything more than that.

Comment: How are you ignoring the events? With UI thread code? If so, then the UI thread is still doing work every time an event fires. You need to fire the events less frequently, rather than ignoring them. Of course your problem may be something completely different, but we can't do much more to help as your question stands.

Comment: Yes its ignored in UI Thread. events are fired as and when data arrives. I will ignore from the worker thread and revert back. thanks

Comment: As others have implied, it's quite easy to stuff up the GUI input queue with too many posted messages from other threads.  Ignoring the events in the GUI thread will help, but the posted messages will still be sent.  If many updates are possible, (eg. in network app with many connections), just update the status with a Forms timer, say, every 500ms, as some other poster suggested.

Comment: Be sure you're not accessing UI objects directly from other threads.  This is easy to do even if you're trying not to, and can cause unpredictable problems.  (It works fine 99.99% of the time, but that 0.01% will kill you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to create your own `WorkQueue` for UI, all other threads will `Enqueue` into that queue and continues its job.

Then use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with some interval and process the queued events accordingly. UI will be responsive.

Comment: I tried ignoring the events and still the problem persists. By any chance is it possible that the Threads created from UI will block the UI ? , since all my threads are created from UI Thread

Comment: No other threads wont block UI. In case you feel there is a block pause the debugger to see where it is running, that will give idea of what's going on

Comment: I created a worker thread to update the UI objects. The issue seems to be reduced but not completely resolved.. I need to look into other UI updations and Database interactions

Answer (score -2):

You can try use Task Parallel Library in `System.Threading.Tasks` Namespace. It utilizes the CPU more and give you better results than using threads or threadpool.  To update the UI, you have to make use of `Dispatcher`.

Please go through following link to understand the Parallel Tasks,

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

EDIT:

```
Action -  delegate or method that has to be done parallely

 Parallel.Invoke(Action, Action,....);
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.?` Task ? It internally uses `ThreadPool`

Comment: No it won't use ThreadPool. Threadpool never utilized all the cores in CPU, but TPL does.

Comment: TPL is not enough, be specific which class? and `Task` class always uses `ThreadPool`(unless you use CustomScheduler or use specify `LongRunning` which creates new `Thread`)

Comment: If you pass the default scheduler for new Task using TaskFactory.StartNew(), it will create a new thread.

Comment: `The default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work. In the .NET Framework 4, the ThreadPool uses the information that is provided by the System.Threading.Tasks.Task type to efficiently support the fine-grained parallelism (short-lived units of work) that parallel tasks and queries often represent.` Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx)

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian Your statement is completely flawed. If a `Task` didn't spawn a `Thread`.. you wouldn't have to use `Dispatcher`. Using your logic, the `Task` would run (by default) within the UI `Thread`.. eliminating the need for `Dispatcher`. If I misunderstand you then I apologise. However, the default `TaskScheduler` will utilise the `ThreadPool`.. you need to pass through an instance of `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` from the UI `Thread` for your statement to be true.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes I misunderstood default scheduler, we have to use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); to make it